# Why does text on Chrome, Firefox, and IE look fuzzier than Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, safari

I've begun writing a new website and ran into this issue, the text on Safari looks very crisp and clean, while text on other browsers looks fuzzy. I've updated all of my browsers and can't find the reason why.Also, I'm running Yosemite as my OS.

Here's a sample screenshot:
http://gyazo.com/11818058c27469040e53650ea5c35e78
Safari on the Left (Sharp), Chrome on the right (Fuzzy)

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Project v2/css/style.css">
<head><title>Company</title></head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul>
<li>about us</li>
<li>Who we are</li>
<li>Contact us</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS:

```
body{
    background: url("/Users/Project/Desktop/Project v2/Assets/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0%;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
nav{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 5;

}
```

Comment: My guess is because of differences both in the rendering engine (WebKit vs Gecko vs Trident) and in the operating system (OSX has been know for its beautiful text rendering). As long as you're not using CSS3 transforms, I guess you have no control over it.

Comment: CSS3 transforms? Also this issue is even worse on older displays that make the text look extremely fuzzy. Is their any way to get that Safari level sharpness across all modern browsers?

Comment: If you talk about “older displays”, then you add more variables you can't control. On the other hand, Sachin's answer may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use 5 in your font-weight,its not a standard value here.

```css
font-weight:500;
```

---

Try another fonts from google fonts or adobe edge web fonts. If font kerning is possibly wrong on rendering engine it might also be a case here. And remember to use either full font stack(.eot and woff) or web service.
Another is to use em's or rem's as main units.They are more useful when a zoomed content goes responsive.